# SQL Query to fetch data between starting and ending null

Tags: sql

I got a requirement in some project where i need data from a table where i need to select top values that starts after a null value and than again some null values and further data

suppose table name is Data which has a single column named as Company

## Company

- NULL
- NULL
- NULL
- Google
- Microsoft
- Oracle
- NULL
- NULL
- Linked In
- Twitter
- Facebook
- NULL
- NULL

in simple words i need to write a query that selects {Google, Microsoft and Oracle} as a result and nothing else .... its just a sample data not my actual project
this data can have hundreds of values between starting null and ending null

Please provide your input to write such query 
Thanks

Comment: SQL tables are inherently unordered, so there is no concept of "next" row *unless* you have a column that specifies the orders, such as an auto incremented id or time stamp.

Comment: suppose i have an auto incremented ID along with company column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming ID is there to keep order... you could do this.  This just find the first non-null ID, and then the next null id - 1 as its range.

```
SELECT *
FROM COMPANY
WHERE ID BETWEEN
    ( SELECT MIN(ID)  
      FROM   COMPANY
      WHERE  COMPANY_NAME IS NOT NULL ) AND
    ( SELECT MIN(ID) - 1
      FROM   COMPANY
      WHERE  COMPANY_NAME IS NULL
      AND    ID > ( SELECT MIN(ID) MIN_ID 
                    FROM   COMPANY
                    WHERE  COMPANY_NAME IS NOT NULL ) )
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/516f9c/1)

Or you could use analytical functions, which would probably be better, assuming you have them in your DBMS.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your immediate response ... it was really helpful ... can you give me an example of analytic function for this ... actually that's what i was really looking for ... Thanks again!

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `lag()`:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*, lag(company) over (order by id) as prev_company
      from data d
     ) d
where prev_company is null and company is not null;
```

If you don't have `lag()`, I would use a correlated subquery:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*, 
             (select d2.company
              from data d2
              where d2.id < d.id
              order by d2.id desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_company
      from data d
     ) d
where prev_company is null and company is not null;
```

Note that in some databases `limit` might be `fetch first row only` or `select top 1` or some other construct.